# How to make the GridList component in React Material-UI responsive

Tags: reactjs, responsive, material-ui

I'm using the Material-UI version 1 to make the grid UI in my React application.  I want to make the grid responsive.  The GridList component API has *cols* props, which by default is *2*.

For example, it could looks like this below.

```
<GridList cols={1} spacing={32} className="list"></GridList>
```

Can I dynamically change the props?  Or are there any other ways to make it responsive?

Answer (score 34):

U can use the [layout breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/) provide by MUI to toggle GridList or GridListTile cols property.
The code will look like this:

```
...
import withWidth, { isWidthUp } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
...

const MyComponent = props => {
  const getGridListCols = () => {
    if (isWidthUp('xl', props.width)) {
      return 4;
    }

    if (isWidthUp('lg', props.width)) {
      return 3;
    }

    if (isWidthUp('md', props.width)) {
      return 2;
    }

    return 1;
  }

  return(
    ...
    <GridList spacing={15} cellHeight={400} cols={getGridListCols()}>
      {
        myItemsArray.map(item => (
          <GridListTile key={item} cols={1}>
            <FooBar />
          </GridListTile>
        ))
      }
    </GridList>
    ...
  );
};

...

export default withWidth()(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Would this update the number of columns when the screen is resized?

Comment: Yes, this will update the number of columns when the screen is resized because the HOC (higher order component) `withWidth` will request a re-render when the browser width changes.  Note: You can now use a [`useWidth`](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#migrating-from-withwidth) React hook as suggested here.

Answer (score 6):

You can choose the `cols` value depending on the width (`xs, sm, md, lg, xl`), look at this example where 1 column is set for smaller screens.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';

// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';

const styles = theme => ({ });

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, currentUser, images, width } = this.props;

        let columns = width === 'xs' || width === 'sm'  ? 1 : 2;

        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <GridList cellHeight={180} cols={columns} className={classes.gridList}>
                    {images.map(image => (
                    <GridListTile key={image.id}>
                        <img src={ image.path } />
                        <GridListTileBar
                            title={ image.name }
                        />
                    </GridListTile>
                    ))}
                </GridList>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    currentUser: PropTypes.object,
    images: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        currentUser: state.user.currentUser
    };
}

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'MyComponent',
  }),
  withWidth(),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Material-UI v4.4, you can [use `useMediaQuery` React hook](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) in conjunction with `theme.breakpoints.up`:

```
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

function MyComponent() {
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.up('sm'));

  return <span>{`theme.breakpoints.up('sm') matches: ${matches}`}</span>;
}
```

⚠️ There is no default theme support, you have to inject it in a parent theme provider.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue and while using @morlo's answer, I did a mistake and it started showing a js error but strangely it also made it responsive! And by responsive, I mean that it shows a horizontal scrolling which is common in mobiles.

So I removed that code and used different values and **cols={0}** worked!

Perhaps it is not documented but it works actually.

Also worth mentioning some other settings that I used along:

```
<GridList style={{
        width: '100%',
        maxHeight: 320,
        flexWrap: 'nowrap'
}} cols={0} cellHeight={'auto'}>
...
</GridList>
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Irrespective of the screen size, a single column is being shown 'partially'.

Answer (score -3):

When you say you want to make the grid responsive, do you perhaps mean adding more items dynamically?  If not, by default `Material-UI` is responsive (meaning your viewport is dynamically sized depending on the device you view on), and depending on your `GridList` properties (like cols, rows, spacing etc) you can determine the style.  If you have a look at https://material-ui-next.com/demos/grid-list/ there are a few examples to get you started.

Comment: @sflow did you find the above helpful in solving your problem?

Comment: It wasn't helpful, as it didn't answer what he was asking for. He was asking how he could dynamically change the `cols` property :)